# create a dropdown list in c# .net server side

Tags: c#, .net

I trie to create a dropdown list in c# .net server side ... but this is not working .. anyone know what is it going wrong here?

```
    string conncetionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection msSQLConnectoin = new SqlConnection(conncetionStr);
    SqlCommand msSQLCommand = msSQLConnectoin.CreateCommand();

    msSQLCommand.CommandText = "app_Event_Type_Select";
    msSQLConnectoin.Open();
    SqlDataReader msDataReader = msSQLCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (msDataReader.Read())
    {
        dropDown.DataSource = msDataReader["Name"].ToString(); 
        dropDown.DataTextField = msDataReader["Name"].ToString();
        dropDown.DataValueField = msDataReader["EventTypeID"].ToString(); 
        dropDown.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: you have a list of names you want to see in the Dropdown ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string conncetionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection msSQLConnectoin = new SqlConnection(conncetionStr);
SqlCommand msSQLCommand = msSQLConnectoin.CreateCommand();

msSQLCommand.CommandText = "app_Event_Type_Select";
msSQLConnectoin.Open();
SqlDataReader msDataReader = msSQLCommand.ExecuteReader();


dropDown.DataSource = msDataReader; 
dropDown.DataTextField = "Name";
dropDown.DataValueField = "EventTypeID"; 
dropDown.DataBind();
msSQLConnectoin.Close();
msSQLConnectoin.Dispose();

dropDown.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Name--");
}
```

Replace `msDataReader["Name"].ToString()` with your data reader name `msDataReader`

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'AFL'.

Comment: are you asking? you are setting DataTextField and DataValueField with actual data! they should be a reference to the field containing the actual data on the DataSource object

Comment: congratulations you just copied the same answer given above...and it seems quite strange since before you clearly had no idea what you were talking about

Comment: i posted my answered before your post answered @DiegoDeVita

Comment: I'm not talking about me. anyway don't want to polemize...I just dislike unfair behaviors. You should be honest.

Comment: if you getting error refer this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1486795.aspx/1) @JinYong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14887/discussion-between-krunal-mevada-and-diego-de-vita)

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      bindDropdownlist()
    }

public void bindDropdownlist()
    {
         SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select colmn1,colmn2 from table", con);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         dap.Fill(ds);
         DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
         DropDownList1.DataTextField = "colmn1";
         DropDownList1.DataValueField = "colmn2";
         DropDownList1.DataBind();
         DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "..select...");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx)
The `DataSource` property is supposed to be set with an object containing all the informations the control needs to be bound to. The `DataTextField` and the `DataValueField` should be a reference to actual data on the `DataSource` object. A simple way to achieve your goal could be to prepare a `DataTable` using `Text` and `Value` fields and then bind the control this way:

```
dropDown.DataSource = dt;
dropDown.DataTextField = "Text";
dropDown.DataValueField = "Value";
dropDown.DataBind();
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) on the msdn web site you'll find your same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the DataTextField and DataValueField should be string representations of the property you've bound, see this [related post](http://forums.devarticles.com/net-development-43/databinding-datatextfield-in-a-drop-down-list-6825.html):

```
 dropDown.DataSource = msDataReader;
 dropDown.DataTextField = "Name";
 dropDown.DataValueField = "EventTypeID";
```